# how to use flask to connect to a database in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, pythonanywhere

i have created a database in the database tab in pythonanywhere
and now i am trying to connect to it so i can get my tables and information from it.

**what is the best way to connect to it and how !?(sqlite3 , SQLAlchemy)**

i used

```
import import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.server",
                 user="username",
                  passwd="password",
                  db="db-name")
```

and it gave me

```
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql.server' (0)")
```

Comment: the problem is that pythonanywhere says the host name is (mysql.server)
and when you put that name in 
my.connect ('mysql.server', 'username-of -db', 'password-of-db', 'database-name')

it will give problems

Comment: That all looks correct to me.  for the database name, it should be in the format "username$databasename", is that what you're using?

Comment: Just to add to what hwjp says above -- in the PythonAnywhere environment, the hostname `mysql.server` is valid, and it maps to the MySQL server instance that is associated with your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating database in pythonanywhere .

How to connect it with python?.

This is python code in which you are going to connect to the database..

```
Import MySQLdb as my

db = my.connect ('database-server-name','username-of -db','password-of-db','database-name')
cursor = db.cursor ()
```

Now your database is connected with your server and python code

Hope this clears!!!
You will get the db server name, username, and the password you created after making database and your database name from the database tab!!

Comment: well , i did try that while i was searching and it gave me this 
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)